# Mixing OOP with structural code

Tags: c++, c

I have a couple of classes in different files. I want to use simple C read from a file mechanism in `main()` function - just read two integers from two files, that's all.

Now, should I create a separate File class and handle it from there?

Should I create standard function in separate `"file.cpp"` file?

Should I write these 3 - 5 lines of code in `main()` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean that you're mixing OOP with procedural programming. If so, good. C++ is designed to leverage both of these together.

If you want to write a function that does not have any state, don't make it a member of a class. Just write a free function called `read_values_from_file` or whatever you want. It's definitely a good practice to identify individual responsibilities in your code and factor them out into functions.

Which file you should put it in depends on whether you'll reuse it at all. If you're only ever going to use it at the beginning of `main`, just put it in `main.cpp`. Don't give it it's own file just for the sake of it. Otherwise, if you want to use the same function across multiple translation units, it might be useful to place its declaration in a header file and its definition in an implementation file.

Regardless of where you put it, do not make this function a member of a class. That's what Java programmers do because they have no choice. C++ trusts you to know when it is most appropriate to create a class: when you have state.

However, I don't imagine you have a very good reason for using any C library functions to read from the file. There's no reason you can't write procedural code that uses the C++ standard library. Just use the file streams, such as [std::istream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), to read the values.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged as c++, I suggest checking the topic of [c++ streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). I don't see why would you have to write file reading related classes.

Comment: I wanted to write this class just to place file stream handling there. That's my question, I can use c++ file stream, but where should I place them in OOP system if I only use them at the very beginning to quickly read two variables from a file?

Comment: in "main.cpp". Unless there is a reason why you would want to do this differently depending on what system you are on, in which case it goes into the "systemdependent.cpp" or some such.

Comment: In that case, you should put them where you need them (i.e. `main()`), and not invent classes for the sake of classes.

Answer (score 0):

This task is so small it's it's hard to say if 'best practices' apply.

Make it work for now, using `scanf` or `std::cin` or whatever is convenient and if you find yourself needing more functionality later then start designing something more robust.

Don't waste a bunch of time overengineering something simple until you know you're going to need those extra features.

Comment: Yes, I know that, YAGNI rule, but it's the homework and reading variables from a file is a requirement.